# Improve JavaScript performance to render Image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, setinterval

I have a simple html code which display an image each 125ms. The target is to display a video captured from a camera.
The image is displayed in a Canvas container and to repeat the *updateImg*() function every time I use setInterval method.

My code still works properly on browser of my PC but less if I use the browser of an old tablet with Android 4 (there is a little latency).

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma-directive' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='cache-directive' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
    <title>Canvas</title>
        <script>
            var img = new Image();
            img.src='http://10.0.9.231:3000/camera?i='+(new Date()).getTime();  
            
            function updateImg(){
                var onScreenContext = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');

                onScreenContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    img.src='http://10.0.9.231:3000/camera?i='+(new Date()).getTime();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="768px" height="432px">
        Canvas not supported
    </canvas>
    <script>
        setInterval(updateImg, 125);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is possible to improve its performaces?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try some Promise?
for exemple some kind of "infinite loop" function with call a Promise and if this Promise resolved you callback the function again